# The query returns wrong result when i want to find who is the shortest player in a NBA Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a NBA script in MySQL and I have to find out who is the shortest player in database. I am using feet as measurement and after executing the query i found out that the player the query was giving me was not the right answer.

The query is

```
select * from players where height=(select min(height) from players);
```

And it gaves me:

```
 '420', 'Carlos Arroyo', 'Florida International', ' 6-2', '202', 'G', 'Magic'
```

where 6-2 is the height.
Instead of giving me one of these results

```
'26', 'Brevin Knight', 'Stanford', '5-10', '170', 'G', 'Clippers'
'113', 'Nate Robinson', 'Washington', '5-9', '180', 'G', 'Knicks'
'182', 'Earl Boykins', 'Eastern michigan', '5-5', '133', 'G', 'Bobcats'
'372', 'Damon Stoudamire', 'Arizona', '5-10', '171', 'G', 'Spurs'
'482', 'Chucky Atkins', 'South Florida', '5-11', '185', 'G', 'Nuggets'
```

And if I order by height players, the result it's a bit annoying:

```
'Carlos Arroyo', ' 6-2'
'Shareef Abdur-Rahim', ' 6-9'
'Louis Amundson', ' 6-9'
'Brevin Knight', '5-10'
'Damon Stoudamire', '5-10'
'Chucky Atkins', '5-11'
'Earl Boykins', '5-5'
'Nate Robinson', '5-9'
'Aaron Brooks', '6-0'
'Allen Iverson', '6-0'
'Kyle Lowry', '6-0'
'Jammer Nelson', '6-0'
'Sebastian Telfair', '6-0'
'Chris Paul', '6-0'
```

Comment: Is `6-2` a measure of height? If it's inches, you should convert them into numeric values.

Comment: You're sorting strings (with and without leading spaces).    The string 5-10 < 5-9

Comment: You appear to be getting confused with what is a string and what is a number; "6-2" is a string, you can't expect values to be ordered as "feet" and "inches". you need an integer column, probably representing inches.

Comment: @Rodr, what lemos is saying is that your field for height is a string value, which doesn't have any meaning for a computer. The field type has to be numeric, like integer, decimal, float etc, in order for a comparison to be made and the results sorted.

Comment: @AltimusPrime. A string value can be ordered and it does have a meaning to a computer. The order for string is alphabetical order, whereas the height in question is a numerical order.

Comment: @slaakso You're right. I should have said it doesn't have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the height-string to a number which you can use for numeric comparison.

```
select player, height
from players
where cast(substring_index(height, '-', 1) as unsigned)*100+
      cast(right(concat('0', substring_index(height, '-', -1)),2) as unsigned) 
      in (
  select min(cast(substring_index(height, '-', 1) as unsigned)*100+
         cast(right(concat('0', substring_index(height, '-', -1)),2) as unsigned))
  from players
)
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IxxKoq9B)

Answer (score 0):

> ...
>
> where 6-2 is the height. Instead of giving me one of these results
>
> ...

You tell that all values `'5-xx'` are equivalent to each other, i.e. only value before the dash is taken into account.

Also you tell that you need in only one output row, and any row of shown 5 rows matches - i.e. you do not need in secondary sorting.

If so then you may simply do

```sql
SELECT *
FROM players
ORDER BY CAST(height AS UNSIGNED) LIMIT 1
```